# How do I run make script on the bash command line? (useful whilst learning)

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to run Make code on the bash cmd line?
Example:

> make -e 'FOO=bar all: @echo Hi there $(FOO)'

-e, --environment-overrides in man make, so some other option that does what I described above.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit? You want to pass makefile contents without using actual makefile? You can use e.g. `printf "all:\n\techo all\n" | make -f -`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make` can read its Makefile from stdin. There are various ways to do this.

```
$ echo 'all:;@echo Hi there $(FOO)' | make -f - FOO=Joe
Hi there Joe
$ make -f - FOO=Joe <<'EOF'
all:;@echo Hi there $(FOO)
EOF
Hi there Joe
$ make -f - FOO=Joe <<< 'all:;@echo Hi there $(FOO)'
Hi there Joe
```

The second one, using a *here-document* in shell parlance, makes it easy to use multi-line Makefiles.

The last one is bash specific because of `<<<`. It won't work portably.

Comment: Is there a way to TAB the commands in the HERE script. If i want to do, all: for d in /tmp/ do echo... done I get /tmp/GmFsmqZo:2: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop. (when I don't insert TAB)

Comment: @Vek.M1234 Yes; tabs in the input are preserved. Did your editor turn them into spaces?

Comment: typed that in xterm (cmd line) - thanks anyway i'll check

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) for this:

```
make -e "FOO=bar" --eval="all:;@echo Hi there $(FOO)"
```